# Java Birthday Calc Logic Error

Tags: java

The calculator only returns the right value if the birthday is in the month after the current month. I have been struggling with this for a while and I do not know how to fix this logic error. Please, any help would be very much appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class BirthdayCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the current month numerically (i.e. if it is July, enter 7)");
        Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
        int monthIs = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter today's date");
        int todayIs = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter person 1's birth month");
        int birthMonthOne = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter person 1's birthday");
        int birthDayOne = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter person 2's birth month");
        int birthMonthTwo = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter person 2's birthday");
        int birthDayTwo = console.nextInt();
        int daysUntilEndOfMonth = getMonth(monthIs, todayIs, 0);
        int totalDaysOne = monthsUntilBirthMonth(monthIs, birthMonthOne, 0);
        int totalDaysTwo = monthsUntilBirthMonth(monthIs, birthMonthTwo, 0);
        finalReport(daysUntilEndOfMonth, totalDaysOne, totalDaysTwo, birthDayOne, birthDayTwo);
    }

    public static int getMonth(int monthIs, int todayIs, int daysUntilEndOfMonth) {
        if (monthIs == 2) {
            daysUntilEndOfMonth = 28 - todayIs; //days until end of february
        } else if (monthIs == 1 || monthIs == 3 || monthIs == 5 || monthIs == 7 || monthIs == 8 || monthIs == 10 || monthIs == 12) {
            daysUntilEndOfMonth = 31 - todayIs; //days until end of months with 31 days
        } else {
            daysUntilEndOfMonth = 30 - todayIs; //days until end of month with 30 days
        }
        return daysUntilEndOfMonth;
    }

    public static int monthsUntilBirthMonth(int initialMonth, int endMonth, int totalDays) {
        if (initialMonth == 12) { // makes sure that largest month is december
            initialMonth = 1;
        } else {
            initialMonth = initialMonth + 1;
        }
        if (initialMonth < endMonth) {
            for (int i = initialMonth; i < endMonth; i++) { //adds total days until birthday until month of birthday is reached
            if (i == 2) {
                totalDays = totalDays + 28;
            } else if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 ||i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 10 || i == 12) {
                totalDays = totalDays + 31;
            }
                totalDays = totalDays + 30;
            }
        } else if (initialMonth > endMonth) { //if the birthday is earlier than the current month, 
            for (int i = endMonth; i <= initialMonth - 1; i++) { //adds total days until birthday until month of birthday is reached
            if (i == 2) {
                totalDays = totalDays + 28;
            } else if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 ||i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 10 || i == 12) {
                totalDays = totalDays + 31;
            }
                totalDays = totalDays + 30;
            }
            totalDays = 365 - totalDays;
        }
        return totalDays;
    }

    public static void finalReport(int daysUntilEndOfMonth, int totalDaysOne, int totalDaysTwo, int birthDayOne, int birthDayTwo) {
        int untilOne = daysUntilEndOfMonth + totalDaysOne + birthDayOne; //calculates days until first person's birthday
        int untilTwo = daysUntilEndOfMonth + totalDaysTwo + birthDayTwo; //calculates days until second person's birthday
        System.out.print("There are " + untilOne + " days until person 1's birthday\n"); //reports number of days until birthday 1
        System.out.print("There are " + untilTwo + " days until person 2's birthday\n"); //reports number of days until birthday 1
        if (untilOne < untilTwo) { //figures out which birthday is sooner
            System.out.println("Person 1's birthday is sooner.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Person 2's birthday is sooner.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here in your question on this site. Let's make it easy as possible to help you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Be careful what you ask for ;)

Comment: I have one word for you [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).  Reduce you're entire code down to like 4 lines

Comment: MadProgrammer true. @NewbieJava What of that wall of code is causing the error?

Comment: @NewbieJava please check the following things while you code **1.** dont ask user for input for some system details like current date and current month. **2.** dont put name for methods like `getMonth` when the method was returning daysUntilEndOfMonth, same goes for `monthsUntilBirthMonth` also. **3.** try not to reinvent wheel - use API like JodaTime as Madprogrammer suggested when ever possible

Comment: I should have explained this in the original thread (please forgive me I am VERY NEW at this). My teacher does not let us use any other methods aside from what I've used up there... very annoying. Therefore JodaTime isn't allowed. I think she is trying to get us to program what these methods would be...

I've worked on this code for days, every time i fix one bug i make another...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (initialMonth < endMonth) {
    for (int i = initialMonth; i < endMonth; i++) { // adds total days until birthday until month of birthday is reached
        if (i == 2) {
            totalDays = totalDays + 28;
        } else if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 10 || i == 12) {
            totalDays = totalDays + 31;
        } else {
            totalDays = totalDays + 30;
        }
    }
} else if (initialMonth > endMonth) { // if the birthday is earlier than the current month,
    for (int i = endMonth; i <= initialMonth - 1; i++) { // adds total days until birthday until month of birthday is reached
        if (i == 2) {
            totalDays = totalDays + 28;
        } else if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 10 || i == 12) {
            totalDays = totalDays + 31;
        } else {
            totalDays = totalDays + 30;
        }
    }
    totalDays = 365 - totalDays;
}
```

You forget to put else block for `totalDays = totalDays + 30;`